# WiFi not working on Dell Inspiron 1564

Tags: 12.04, wireless, dell

hope you can offer some help!

I'm new to Ubuntu (and Linux for that matter), but I managed to install Ubuntu 12.04 yesterday on an old Dell Inspiron 1564 Laptop. Everything works fine, with the exception of the wireless connection.

Using my wired ethernet, I was able to look up several solutions which seemed as if they would work, but I've had no luck.

Currently, wireless does show as enabled, but all wireless networks are disconnected, in fact, none of the networks are even listed (and I can see them on other devices in the home).

Let me know what you need to help me! Thanks in advance!

```
lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0c45:6461 Microdia 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 1058:0730 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 045e:0745 Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver v1.0 for Bluetooth

rfkill list
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Edit your question, and add the output of `lsusb` and `rfkill list`.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BroadcomSTA%28Wireless%29

This may help.  If it is anything like my 1501, DO NOT install the restricted WIFI driver.  That crashed Ubuntu.

Follow the steps under Install with Internet first.  You have to uninstall the other drivers if present then install the right drivers above it.

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't seem to get me anywhere.